# How can I disable (only) the rear facing camera?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, camera

I have a Droid Maxx running Android 4.4, but the rear facing camera has a problem. I tried replacing it once, and it worked for a few minutes, but went bad again. The front facing camera works fine.

Because all the apps tend to default to the rear facing camera, I end up not being able to use the camera at all. (The rear camera just freezes the app when it is activated.) It would be really nice to be able to use the front camera, since that one still works fine. (If I can find a way to activate it before the rear camera locks up the app.)

I found several apps on Google Play that will disable all the cameras, but I didn't see any that **let you disable just the rear camera** while keeping the front active. Is there an app or a setting that would allow me to do this?

The phone is using the stock Verizon bootloader and is not rooted. Thanks in advance for any tips in this regard!! I love the phone, I just miss the camera.

Comment: I'd check for "[selfie cameras](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=selfie%20camera)". Being specialized on selfies, those should start with the front camera enabled – at least I'd expect that. Not tested though :)

Comment: @Izzy - Good thought... I will have to check into that.  :-)

Comment: Good luck – and don't forget to let us know the outcome then :) Oh: and careful to not pick a "spy cam" that reports back somewhere else before you're ready #D